# Import array indices from Excel

Tags: list-manipulation, excel

In an Excel file, I have some numbers which I will use as the indices of arrays. I want to read those numbers and assign them as the array indices in *Mathematica*.

For instance, in Excel I have

[image]

and I want the rows to be imported as follows in *Mathematica*:

```
{{x[[1]], x[[1]], x[[10]], x[[12]], x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[11]], x[[3]]},
 {x[[1]], x[[1]], x[[12]], x[[14]], x[[1]], x[[3]], x[[13]], x[[4]]},
 ... }
```

Link to download the excel file: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/477a157f

Comment: Could you please explain more? I am a beginner user.

Comment: The array numbers to be imported are as the picture above. My data is that.

Comment: No, that is the excel file in which the numbers are stored, I want mathematica to use those numbers as array counters. But I don't know how.

Comment: I added the data to the question.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another version:

```
Import["~/Downloads/NodeNumbers.xlsx"] /. ind_Real :> x[[Floor@ind]]
```

Comment: It worked for me. I used the following syntaxes in the next comments:

Comment: x = Flatten[Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "x.xlsx"}]]];

Comment: Flatten[Import[
   FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "NodeNumbers.xlsx"}]] /. 
  ind_Real :> x[[Floor@ind]], 1]

Answer (score 1):

Given your data in the link, e.g.:

```
arrayList = 
 Map[x[[#]] &, 
  First@Round[Import["c:\\users\\rasher\\downloads\\nodenumbers.xlsx"]], {2}];
```

will give you the symbol `arrayList` containing the list of lists of `x` indexed using the values in the spreadsheet.

Note that if `x` does not already exist with enough values, you'll get error messages. You can append `//Quiet` to the above if you just want a list of lists of indexed `x` - if/when you create and fill `x`, `arrayList` entries will take on the appropriate values. The messages (if `x` does not exist in proper form) are from attempting to reference something non-existent. You could also `Hold` the entries to avoid this, but I'm not clear what the end result you're after is...

If there's something else you had in mind, you'll need to further clarify your question.

Comment: note you can do the Map on level 1 just as well : `x[[#]] & /@ First@Round[Import["file.xlsx"]]`  -- might be a tad faster, then again the excel import performance likely dwarfs that difference.